# VMware Guest machine NIC errors

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-esxi, interface

I am running Linux `CentOS 5.11 with 32bit Arch` I have seen NIC generating many interface errors

```
[root@centos5 ~]$ /sbin/ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:97:C0:0E
          inet addr:10.0.0.211  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe97:c00e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:522097243 errors:652681 dropped:40319 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2249903102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:446749739 (426.0 MiB)  TX bytes:1726106831 (1.6 GiB)
          Interrupt:59 Base address:0x2000
```

Linux Driver is, PCnet32

```
[root@centos5 ~]$ /sbin/lsmod | grep pcnet32
pcnet32                35141  0
mii                     9409  1 pcnet32
```

Do you think it could me `Low Memory` issue on OS?  Or Driver issue?

Comment: Firstly you should be using vmxnet not pcnet32, secondly it's 2015 what are you doing with 5.11-32bit!!!?! you also don't mention which version of ESXi you're running either but I'm pretty sure your issues are these, the drive one in particular, you should be running the latest vmtools.

Comment: because of application limitation we have to use CentOS5/32bit OS. Lets not talk about that because it is big topic. We are using `ESXi 4.x` We are running `VMTools` Just wanted to confirm its driver issue or memory

Comment: Everything's all so old - essentially it's unsupported and this site is for supported/supportable solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Intel e1000 or VMware vmxnet3 adapters for your OS.

Can you try adjusting the adapter type and testing again?

Make sure the VMware tools are installed.